# How to call ffmpeg.exe to convert audio files on Windows Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage

I run a Web Role on Windows Azure to receive AAC audio files (uploaded by base64 string) and store them into blob. it works fine by now.

Next, I also have to convert them into MP3 and store the MP3s into blob too. I decided to use something like **ffmpeg.exe -i *path*.aac *path*.mp3**.

The problems are that:

1. How to **call external ffmpeg.exe** inside a web service of a web role?
2. what would be the ***path***?

Please help me if you know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest that you use a [Local Storage Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx) for your webrole where you can download the AAC files from the blob storage, and have them converted to MP3. Then upload back to blob storage.

Side note is that you can also use the [Path.GetTempFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx) to get a temporary file name for your AAC / MP3 files, but I don't encourage to do so (even if I've done it before).

As for the actuall ffmpeg running, you might want to browse the code for [AzureVideoConv](http://azurevideoconv.codeplex.com/), which I've built some time ago. You will find a lot of useful code there.

Here is a sample of the actual ffmpeg call (note that I download the exe from a blob storage, to avoid bloating my azure package with external exe files, and to easily update the ffmpeg.exe when required):

```
        internal void ConvertFile(string inputFileName, Guid taskID)
    {
        string tmpName = string.Format(
            "{0}\\{1}.flv",
            Path.GetTempPath(), inputFileName.Substring(inputFileName.LastIndexOf("\\")+1));
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = this._processorExecutable;
        psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-i ""{0}"" -y ""{1}""", inputFileName, tmpName);
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.ErrorDialog = false;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                string outString = string.Empty;
                // use ansynchronous reading for at least one of the streams
                // to avoid deadlock
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => {
                    outString += e.Data;
                };
                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                // now read the StandardError stream to the end
                // this will cause our main thread to wait for the
                // stream to close (which is when ffmpeg quits)
                string errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Trace.WriteLine(outString);
                Trace.TraceError(errString);
                byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(tmpName);
                if (fileBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    this._sSystem.SaveOutputFile(
                        fileBytes, 
                        tmpName.Substring(tmpName.LastIndexOf("\\")+1),
                        taskID
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE** the last check in of the project is using Windows Azure SDK 1.3

Comment: I have read this 1h ago, thank you for your great work! but I am not good at C# so I don't know how to use it in my context. I have configure the Local Storage Resource of my web role (not worker role), then how to download the .exe and .aac from blob? how to run it? how to upload .mp3 back?

Comment: Please take a closer look at my code at: http://azurevideoconv.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5501 becasue there are too many questions now and all of them are answered in my code :) You can use the discussions on the CodePlex's project site to ask additional questions.

Comment: OK. There're three versions. which one should I use?

Comment: I have done! thank you for your work. I have answer this question by myself, because your answer is not specific. However, my answer is based on your code (as I noted), so I accepted your answer. Please upvote my answer if you like it:-)

Answer (score 8):

Thank you a lot @astaykov. You did a good job. Though It's not specific for my case(I need a specific piece of code instead of a whole large project), but it really inspired me. For specifying into my case, I am going to answer this question by my own - note that **I did this based on @astaykov's code with somewhere directly copy&paste**.

1. Firstly, configure the role with a [Local Storage Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx). Then get its path by these code:

   ```
       LocalResource converter_path = 
              RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("AudioConvertSpace");
       string rootPathName = converter_path.RootPath;
   ```
2. get the path of *ffmpeg.exe*, *xxx.aac* and *xxx.mp3* in the local storage:

   ```
       string aac_path = rootPathName + "\\" + "fmwa-" + guidguid + ".aac";
       string mp3_path = rootPathName + "\\" + "fmwa-" + guidguid + ".mp3";
       string exe_path = rootPathName + "\\" + "ffmpeg.exe";
   ```
3. write the .aac file to local storage:

   ```
       System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(aac_path, decoded_audio_byte_array);
   ```
4. keep in mind that the local storage is not guaranteed to be stable or durable, so check the existence of the ffmpeg.exe -- if it doesn't exist, download it from blob.

   ```
       if (System.IO.File.Exists(exe_path) == false)
       {
           var exeblob = _BlobContainer.GetBlobReference("ffmpeg.exe");
           exeblob.DownloadToFile(exe_path, null);
       }
   ```
5. initial and run the ffmpeg.exe process:

   ```
       ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
       psi.FileName = exe_path;
       psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-i ""{0}"" -y ""{1}""", 
                                          aac_path, mp3_path);
       psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
       psi.ErrorDialog = false;
       psi.UseShellExecute = false;
       psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
       psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
       Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi);
       exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
       string outString = string.Empty;
       exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => {
                   outString += e.Data;
               };
       exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
       string errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
       Trace.WriteLine(outString);
       Trace.TraceError(errString);
       exeProcess.WaitForExit();
   ```
6. upload the output of ffmpeg.exe into the blob storage:

   ```
       byte[] mp3_audio_byte_array = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(mp3_path);
       var mp3blob = _BlobContainer.GetBlobReference("fmwa-"+guidguid+".mp3");
       mp3blob.Properties.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
       mp3blob.UploadByteArray(mp3_audio_byte_array);
   ```
7. clean the temp files:

   ```
       System.IO.File.Delete(aac_path);
       System.IO.File.Delete(mp3_path);
   ```

Comment: Great! I'm glad that I could help. I would only like to comment on (4) about durability of the storage. The storage is guaranteed to be durable for the time your VM is UP. So you could download your EXE just once on the "OnStart()" method of your RoleEntryPoint descendand. There is an option (checkbox) to keep local storage content upon role recycling. The only time when the content will be wiped out is upon ReImaging or Healing (in both cases you will go through the OnStart() and will be able to download the EXE).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the only thing what I want to make sure. I am glad that it will be downloaded only once. The reason why do I write it like this is that the [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx) said **You can specify that a local storage resource be preserved when an instance is recycled. However, data that is saved to the local file system of the virtual machine is not guaranteed to be durable**. Anyway, it works and thank you!

Comment: Skyler, can you share your code project for the azure audio conversion? This is really useful and I would like to try the project out.

Comment: @Zap All the code to convert audio with Azure are shown in this answer, you might want to just simply write them in sequence. The code project is confidential under the NDA of my employer, so I can not share it. If you have any further problem, please feel free to ask, I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Azure and want to create a RESTful web service to upload audio to Azure and kick off the process you described above to convert to mp3. Can you post code & links to step by step on how I can quickly get started on this?

Comment: the answer above **IS** just the code to do so. If you can not understand the code, I think You might want to go through the official training course: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazure_unit firstly.

Comment: Thanks Skyler for the response and info. Do you know how I can set up the worker role you described to trigger once a new blob is uploaded to Azure?

Comment: My example didn't use worker role at all. If you need it, then it would become another huge question: How to use a worker role? I don't think it's a proper question here, you'd better go through the tutorial.