# Running a Console from an Azure Worker Role - Do not have permissions

Tags: c#, azure

Hello  I am trying to run a console app from a Worker Role (as per user demand) but the console fails to execute completely.

I am doing :

```
Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ZProcessing";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "argument" //example
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.UserName = "man1";
                string pass = "lolol213";
                SecureString str = new SecureString();
                char[] chArray = pass.ToCharArray();
                foreach (char c in chArray)
                {
                    str.AppendChar(c);
                }
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
```

I have also tried `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` with `proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` but same error..I know the console does not even start because just at the begining it is supposed to create a log file..

Now, I did hardcoded the console, copy pasted it into the server, executed it there and it does create all the files folders and carries on with the analisis it has to do..

So it is either I am executing it wrongly..or I dont execute it with the enough permissions or something..Or also the combination of Worker Role + Console app is not working.. Help¿?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call ffmpeg.exe to convert audio files on Windows Azure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725946/how-to-call-ffmpeg-exe-to-convert-audio-files-on-windows-azure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725946/how-to-call-ffmpeg-exe-to-convert-audio-files-on-windows-azure). I've provided very detailed explanation on how to run external process and what to be careful about. There are also some additional comments by the original question author.