# Converting Video files in a Azure Webjob with ffMpeg

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-webjobs

I'm having trouble using ffMpeg in an Azure webjob.

I found the following article ([How to call ffmpeg.exe to convert audio files on Windows Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725946/how-to-call-ffmpeg-exe-to-convert-audio-files-on-windows-azure)) and it is exactly what I want to do, however, I cannot get ffMpeg to execute and it gives no error message.

To diagnose the problem, I have boiled it down to its essentials by uploading ffMpeg, a video file to convert, and batch file to run it:

[image: files in directory]

The script in `run.cmd` is simply:

```
del output.mp4
ffmpeg -i screencast.wmv -c:v libx264 -r 15 output.mp4
```

This works on my personal machine, but ran as a webjob I get results below.

```
[12/08/2015 15:42:39 > bf9dd6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[12/08/2015 15:42:39 > bf9dd6: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'ffmpegtest\output.mp4' exists in source directory but not in working directory.
[12/08/2015 15:42:47 > bf9dd6: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[12/08/2015 15:42:48 > bf9dd6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running<br />
[12/08/2015 15:42:48 > bf9dd6: INFO] 
[12/08/2015 15:42:48 > bf9dd6: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\ffMpeg\y1bdnb1e.03k\ffmpegtest>del output.mp4 
[12/08/2015 15:42:48 > bf9dd6: INFO] 
[12/08/2015 15:42:48 > bf9dd6: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\ffMpeg\y1bdnb1e.03k\ffmpegtest>ffmpeg -i screencast.wmv -c:v libx264 -r 15 output.mp4 
[12/08/2015 15:42:49 > bf9dd6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[12/08/2015 15:42:49 > bf9dd6: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -1073741515
```

Edit:
Additionally, it was suggested that I run using Kudu console.  Still no luck:
[image: Kudu Screenshot]

Solution:
I ended up needing to run the 32 version of ffMpeg and not the 64 bit.  Thanks so much @mathewc !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have improved your question to be easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to enclose your input/output file names in quotes in your `run.cmd` file so they expand properly.

```
ffmpeg -i "screencast.wmv" -c:v libx264 -r 15 "output.mp4"
```

For the future, the best way to diagnose these types of problems is to run your commands in your [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to get detailed output info from your exe. That allows you to test things as you would locally, and to address any slight discrepancies that may exist when running in the Azure environment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Kudu console!  I ran it and got the same thing.  I added a screenshot to the post.  Just comes back blank.

Comment: I have your scenario running in my own webjob. I'm able to run the above command and it correctly produces an mp4 file. Please try again :)

Comment: Sorry to be taking up a lot of your time. What version of ffmpeg are you running?  The one I am trying is the 64 bit ffmpeg version N-75204-g314bc20.

Comment: I downloaded the 32 bit Static version from here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. It looks above like `ffmpeg -version` also produces no output for you? It does for me.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much.  I uploaded the 32 bit version and I just ran it successfully!

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into some [sandbox restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). To help isolate, I suggest trying to run your command directly from [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) to take the WebJobs part out of the equation.