# Easy way to resize azure VM automatically

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We have a VM on azure and this VM is a 20-core which is pretty expensive. This vm is used by agents of the company that work from 8am to 5pm. After this time, there is almost no use.

I want to try to reduce the cost by resizing this vm to a 2-core size after 5:10pm and resize it back to 20-core on 7:50am. I've been doing this manually for over a week now and it seems to be saving a good money.

The problem is that I'm doing this manually and I would like to make it automatically.

I've been reading that this can be done if I have an availability set configured. But when this vm was created, an availability set was not for some reason and the vm needs to be recreated in order to have one, but this is not an option.

Maybe I can use powershell to do this? I have a very basic knowledge of powershell so I don't know how this could be done.

If I could create a powershell script and use the scheduled tasks of windows to run it on those specific hours, that would be great.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you doing that necessitates having twenty CPU cores? Is this a desktop or a web-application or something else? Are you self-hosting SQL Server (or any other kind of database?) Have you evaluated other IAAS/PASS options (such as off-loading the database to Azure SQL)?

Comment: There is just a dynamic video rendering service that is exposed through a rest service and is used by an android app. That's all I know.

Comment: it uses a sql database but it's not hosted on the same server, it's an azure sql I believe

Comment: @user3900456 Have you looked to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/media-services/ ?

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks! Meanwhile the resizing is the fastest option to save some money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change machine size you can run powershell

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "MySvc1" -Name "MyVM3" | Set-AzureVMSize "Small" | Update-AzureVM
```

[Here is example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34556.schedule-powershell-scripts-to-manage-azure-virtual-machines.aspx) how to automate.

But here is also a problem if you run resize command machine will be rebooted, so if you are using one machine you will not process anything for some period of time.

I would also suggest you to look to [webjobs with queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-queues-how-to). It will give you flexibility of processing

- You will be able to autoscale depends on demand (So you will choose basic size and as soon as cpu usage grow you can say add one more node and so on, if cpu is reduced azure will shotdown nodes)
- You can use queue to push tasks and webjob will pick it up.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try. And no problem about rebooting.

Comment: I know nothing about your app but usually if you have service its easy to convert to webjob (again it depends on app) but with webjobs you will be more flexible ;)

Comment: all I know about azure is that I can host vms on it :) I need to study more about it to know what I can do. Thanks

Comment: I see that our service uses ffmpeg, can I use it with webjobs?

Comment: @user3900456 Why not? Webjob is like a window service but with more features(you can schedule, you can run continuously), so you are not limited to anything

Comment: I mean, ffmpeg is a command line tool that needs to be installed. And I use it using c# (Process.Start). Is this possible to install custom programs to use with Webjobs?

Comment: See similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160480/converting-video-files-in-a-azure-webjob-with-ffmpeg

Comment: So assume you dont need to install, but you can bundle exe file with webjob

Answer (score 0):

Certain VM sizes aren't attainable unless you disable accelerated networking first.

If, like me, you want to enable accelerated networking whenever possible, only disable it when it's not, the following powershell module is something I put together to automatically handle scaling a VM and disabling accelerated networking if necessary.

```powershell
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [object] $ResourceGroupName,
    
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [object] $VMName,

    [Parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
    [object] $NewVMSize
)


Function Get-TimeStamp {    
    return "[{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)    
}

Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Importing Modules"
Import-Module -Name Az.Automation
Import-Module -Name Az.Compute
Import-Module -Name Az.Network
Import-Module -Name Az.Resources

Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Validating Arguments"
if (-Not $ResourceGroupName) {
    Write-Error "$(Get-TimeStamp) Runbook was missing the expected ""ResourceGroupName"" property. Args were: $args"
    exit 0
}
if (-Not $VMName) {
    Write-Error "$(Get-TimeStamp) Runbook was missing the expected ""VMName"" property. Args were: $args"
    exit 0
}

# Set the current automation connection's authenticated account to use for future Azure Resource Manager cmdlet requests.
Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Obtaining Service Principle Connection..."
$ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -ErrorAction Stop `
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose
Set-AzContext -Subscription $ServicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID -ErrorAction Stop | Write-Verbose 
Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Logged in as AzureRunAsConnection Service Principle"

# Get the VM to be scaled up or down
Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Retrieving VM Information"
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -ErrorAction Stop
# Check if the VM already has the requested configuration
if ($vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize -eq $NewVMSize) {
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Nothing to do! The VM already has the configuration $NewVMSize"
    exit 1
}

# Collect information about the VM's network configuration
Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Retrieving Network Interface Information..."
$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceId $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces[0].id -ErrorAction Stop

try {
    # Change the configuration
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Changing VM Configuration..."
    $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize = $NewVMSize    
    Update-AzVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Successfully updated the VM configuration to $NewVMSize"
} catch {
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Handling error while changing VM Configuration..."
    # Some VM configurations do not support accelerated networking. Try to correct that
    if ($_.Exception.Message.Contains("VMSizeIsNotPermittedToEnableAcceleratedNetworking")) {
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) It appears as though the new VM Size was not accepted because it does not support Accelerated Networking."
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Attempting to disable Accelerated Networking on the VM's network interface: $($nic.Name)..."
        $nic.EnableAcceleratedNetworking = $False
        try {
            $nic | Set-AzNetworkInterface -ErrorAction Stop
        } catch {
            Write-Error "$(Get-TimeStamp) Error while disabling accelerated networking: $_"
            throw
        }
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Done. Now trying to change the VM Configuration again..."
        try {
            Update-AzVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Successfully updated the VM configuration to $NewVMSize"
        } catch {
            Write-Error "$(Get-TimeStamp) Unexpected error while updating the VM configuration after disabling accelerated networking: $_"
            throw
        }
    } else {
        Write-Error "$(Get-TimeStamp) Unexpected error while updating the VM configuration. Error code is: $($_.Exception.ErrorCode). Full Details: $_"
        throw
    }
} finally {
    # Try to restore Accelerated Networking regardless of what actions succeeded/failed above
    if (-Not $nic.EnableAcceleratedNetworking) {
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Attempting to restore accellerated networking on the VM..."
        try { 
            $nic.EnableAcceleratedNetworking = $True
            $nic | Set-AzNetworkInterface -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Restored Accelerated Networking on the network interface: $($nic.Name)"
        } catch {
            # This is expected to fail if we have configured the VM to a size that does not support it.    
            Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Retrieving VM Information..."        
            $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Accelerated Networking not supported on the network interface $($nic.Name) with the current VM size $($vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize)"
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your use-case, you may have no need for the service-principle stuff, mine was to host this in an Azure Automation Runbook.

Here are some VM sizes to try it with as of the time this was posted:

```powershell
# SCALE UP: Here are the best-value memory optimized VM configurations as of 2021-01-01
# VM                 vCPUs  RAM (GiB)
# Standard_E2as_v4   2      16
# Standard_E4as_v4   4      32
# Standard_E8as_v4   8      64
# Standard_E16as_v4  16     128
# Standard_E20as_v4  20     160
# Standard_E32as_v4  32     256
# Standard_E48as_v4  48     384
# Standard_E64as_v4  64     512
# Standard_E96as_v4  96     672   <- Note: sub-linear increase in RAM per cost makes this slightly worse value
#
# SCALE DOWN: Here are the lowest-cost VM configurations that meet the minimum-spec for windows 10
# VM        vCPUs   RAM (GiB)   Cost/month
# Standard_B1ms     1       2           US$15.11
# Standard_B2s      2       4           US$30.37
# Standard_F1s      1       2           US$36.28
# Standard_DS1_v2   1       3.5         US$53.29
# Standard_DS1      1       3.5         US$56.21
# Standard_B2ms     2       8           US$60.74
# Standard_F2s_v2   2       4           US$61.76
# Standard_D2as_v4  2       8           US$70.08
# Standard_F2s      2       4           US$72.27
```